# I am unable to stop or kill consumer receive(0), please help me how to shutdown activemq consumer if the waiting time is zero millisec

Tags: java, activemq-classic

```
private boolean isRunning=false;
          try {
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("username","password",ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        // Create a Connection
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        // Create the destination
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("testQ");
        consumer = (ActiveMQMessageConsumer) session.createConsumer(destination);
       do {
            System.out.println("Waiting for message...");
            Message message = consumer.receive(0);
            if (message != null && message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) message;
                System.out.println("Received: " + txtMsg.getText());
            }
            isRunning=true;
        } while (isRunning);

} catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am not familiar with activemq, I merely investigated and read through [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQMessageConsumer.html). For something like this, you can almost always find the solution there, as this would likely be considered a common problem.*

From what I can tell, you're waiting **synchronously** for a message to be received, and you've set **no timeout**. As a result, the thread in which this occurs is blocked forever (as you're experiencing).

In order to cancel the `ActiveMQMessageConsumer` object, you will need to call the [`close()`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQMessageConsumer.html#close()) method. However, in your case, if I'm correct that you're calling `receive` synchronously, you will have to implement some kind of multi-threaded environment, in which the second thread is not blocked, and can call `close()` on the consumer object.